# Fail-safe importing data: Matching term?

Tags: terminology

I am searching the matching term for this problem:

System-1 has a directory containing files.

1. system-1 sends the data to system-2
2. system2 imports the data.
3. system-2 sends an acknowledgement to system-1
4. system-1 deletes/moves the local data

A power-failure or bug can happen every time.

If the acknowledgement gets lost, then system-1 will try to send the data again.

Now the data gets imported twice, which is a failure. Data should get imported once.

This question is not about a solution to the issue, this question is about how to call this problem.

What is the matching term for this?

Example: System-1 could be a mail-server and system-2 could be an issue system which imports mails.

Comment: What about *Data pipeline between two systems* or [Solution stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) (even though you are talking about systems rather than applications)?

Comment: @B--rian what is the difference between system and application according to your point of view?

Comment: @B--rian Solution stack does not fit. My question is not about layers where one build on top of the other. System-1 and system-2 are standalone systems/applications. I added an example.

Comment: I guess this tries to solve the problem. But I could not find a name for the problem on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

Comment: System is IMHO more general than application. A system can be a set of applications.

Comment: @B--rian does it matter for this question if I use the term "system" or "application"?

Comment: It depends. I mean, there is [Systems theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory) and [Shannon's information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematical_Theory_of_Communication) offering the wider, general framework and scientific terms. For interacting applications, that framework might be a bit overkill.

Comment: You might call you problem also *Making a ecosystem of applications fail-safe* to use a few more IT buzzwords, if your clients have trouble with abstract terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be attributed to the scenario called [Two Generals' Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).

It is a thought experiment which illustrates the complications arise in the communication between two system which are connected through an unreliable media.

According to Wikipedia, this is...

> meant to illustrate the pitfalls and design challenges of attempting
>   to coordinate an action by communicating over an unreliable link. In
>   the experiment, two generals are only able to communicate with one
>   another by sending a messenger through enemy territory. The experiment
>   asks how they might reach an agreement on the time to launch an
>   attack, while knowing that any messenger they send could be captured.

However, this issue is addressed to a greater extent in computer networking by the TCP mechanism sending [acknowledgements](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2016/0021220.html) between every packet switching nodes.

Comment: When reading this answer, I was immediately asking myself how to generalize it to more than two systems. And the [Mongo Arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/) came into my mind, this arbiter is necessary to avoid [stalemate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalemate) situations when different systems have to quickly come to a decision about a state.

Comment: The Two generals problem is well recognized phenomena and is applicable to communication between more than two systems. The building block of any multitude of communication is the basic communication between two nodes and the phenomena applies there. So, it is the most general form of the problem already.